# How can I add an image watermark to the text-wrapping image on bottom right?

Tags: php, laravel

Here is the code to generate a text-wrapping image. How can I add a image watermark to the text-wrapping image on bottom right ? Thanks.

```
private function warpTextImage($text)
{
    $font = $this->font;
    $text_dimensions = imagettfbbox(30, 0, $font, $text);
    $text_width = abs($text_dimensions[4] - $text_dimensions[0]);
    $text_height = abs($text_dimensions[5] - $text_dimensions[1]);
    $img_width = abs($text_dimensions[4] - $text_dimensions[0]) + 40;
    $img_height = abs($text_dimensions[5] - $text_dimensions[1]) + 40;
    $image = imagecreate($img_width, $img_height);
    $background = imagecolorallocate($image, $this->background_color[0], $this->background_color[1], $this->background_color[2]);
    $color = imagecolorallocate($image, $this->text_color[0], $this->text_color[1], $this->text_color[2]);
    $x = ($img_width - $text_width) / 2 - 4;
    $y = ($img_height - $text_height) / 2 + 30;
    imagettftext($image, 30, 0, $x, $y, $color, $font, $text);
    return $image;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`insert()`](http://image.intervention.io/api/insert) method of [Intervention package](http://image.intervention.io) for this:

```
$img->insert('public/watermark.png', 'bottom-right', 10, 10);
```